# How to position out a label inside RadHtmlChart

Tags: asp.net, telerik, rad, radchart

I am using Telerik version 2013. I want to display y values, for example, 4, 6, 5, 12, and 4 inside a RadChart. How can I do that?
Currently, my output is like:

[image]

ASPX code:

```
<telerik:RadScriptManager ID="RadScriptManager1" runat="server">
</telerik:RadScriptManager>
<telerik:RadHtmlChart
    ID="RadHtmlChart"
    runat="server"
    Legend-Appearance-Visible="true"
    Legend-Appearance-Position="Bottom"
    Width="250px"
    Height="250px">
    <PlotArea>
        <Series>
            <telerik:PieSeries>
                <LabelsAppearance>
                    <TextStyle Margin="-30" />
                </LabelsAppearance>
            </telerik:PieSeries>
        </Series>
    </PlotArea>
</telerik:RadHtmlChart>
```

ASPX.CS code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SeriesItem s1 = new SeriesItem(6);
    s1.Name = "A";

    SeriesItem s2 = new SeriesItem(5);
    s2.Name = "B";

    SeriesItem s3 = new SeriesItem(12);
    s3.Name = "C";

    SeriesItem s4 = new SeriesItem(4);
    s4.Name = "D";

    SeriesItem s5 = new SeriesItem(4);
    s5.Name = "E";

    PieSeries ps = new PieSeries();
    ps.Items.Add(s1);
    ps.Items.Add(s2);
    ps.Items.Add(s3);
    ps.Items.Add(s4);
    ps.Items.Add(s5);
    ps.LabelsAppearance.Position = Telerik.Web.UI.HtmlChart.PieLabelsPosition.Column;
    ps.TooltipsAppearance.Visible = false;

    RadHtmlChart.PlotArea.Series.Add(ps);
    RadHtmlChart.DataBind();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look here: http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/htmlchart-server-side-api-configure-series.html.
In the Attribute properties in [SeriesType] > **LabelsAppearance** section -  there is a **Position** property that you need to set to **InsideEnd**.

IMPORTANT: upgrade to the latest version, I think this is a new feature :)